# How to call a java class using jsp page

Tags: java

I want to call a java class using jsp. `SendMail.java` is a program for sending mail, and is in an email package having only a main method.

Can I call the class file using a button, using a form action?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer:  yes.  Long answer:  Yes, but it really depends on what you're doing - are you doing this with JSP and JSTL?  Are you using some sort of framework?  Are you just embedding Java code into your JSP (please don't do this very often for all that is good and righteous in the world)?

Comment: call the class file in form action. because it would be global for all actions

Answer (score 0):

Use form to post action to an another servlet. Servlet is a class that can call SendMail class method.

Or you can use link in jsp or html to call get method in a servlet.